# Vuex access modules state in from store

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vuex4

I have a Vuex store that is split up into multiple modules. Each of these modules has it's own state.

I cannot seem to get this to work I always get an error stating that `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined`. I don't know what I do wrong.

This is the index.js of my Vue store:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

import layers from './modules/layers';

export const store = createStore({
  modules: {
    layers,
  },
});
```

This is the module I am trying to access:

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
      areas: [],
  },
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
  getters: {},
};
```

Here I try to access the state that is being defined:

```
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

export default function useAddExistingFeatures() {
  const store = useStore();
  const area = store.layers.state.areas[1];
}
```

My main.js. The plugins.js is just a file to load my css files.

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import { store } from './store';

import './plugins';

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app');
```

Comment: `store = new Vuex.Store({` is the syntax of vuex 3 which is not compatible with vue 3

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have updated it to the newer syntax of Vuex. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: how did you add it to the main.js

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have added my main.js. I haven't changed anything here since the creation of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get access to the `state` field before the module name :

```
const area = store.state.layers..areas[1];
```

instead of  `const area = store.layers.state.areas[1];`